# Webpack dynamic imports with Typescript Types

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, webpack, dynamic-import

I am using Firebase in my Next.js React application with Typescript. Since the Javascript Firebase package is so large, I am attempting to use the webpack dynamic imports feature to "lazy-load" the package into my project, like so:

```js
const _firebase = await Promise.all([import("firebase/app"), import("firebase/firestore")])
```

I later use the `_firebase` constant to access Firebase throughout the application.

Since I am using Typescript, I also need access to the Firebase type definitions included within their respective packages. This requires me to use `import firebase from "firebase"` at the top of all my .ts and .tsx files. However, this would void the advantages of "lazy-loading" if I am regularly importing the firebase package.

How can I utilize the advantages of webpack dynamic imports, while also having access to the Firebase typescript type definitions?

Comment: `Promise.all` returns an array. The language understands dynamic imports just fine

Comment: @AluanHaddad it does work for the `_firebase` variable, but there are variables other places in the code that require the type definitions. For example, I have an `Auth` class that has an instance variable for the Google Auth Provider that gets defined in the constructor. It has the type `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider`, but that is only accessibly through manually importing the Firebase. package

Comment: If you just import a module only to use the types, not the values, the compiler will elode the `import`. Alternatively, you can write `import type` instead of `import` to enforce that an import is only used in type positions and thus is elided.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I did not know about the `import type` capability, I think that will solve my problem! Thank you!